# Java Jung casting and getTrees()

Tags: java, casting, tree, jung

I am using the Java Jung 2.01 graph package to do some analysis in Graph Theory. My algorithm takes a `Forest<V, E>` so that I may then cast to a `DelegateForest<V,E>` so I may use the `getTrees()` method to get instances for the components of the forest. My algorithm is recursive and will execute on each component from the `getTrees()` method.

So, the problem is the return type for `getTrees()` which is a collection of `Tree<V, E>` Since my algorithm takes a `Forest<V, E>` (and at some point casts to `DelegateForest<V, E>`) and I wish to execute my algorithm on each tree component of my forest,  I get a ClassCastException stating that I cannot convert from `DelegateTree<V, E>` to `DelegateForest<V, E>`.

Here is some of my code: `ArrayList<Forest<String, Integer>> treeComps = new ArrayList<Forest<String, Integer>>(forest.getTrees());`

This first line just stores the tree components of forest into an ArrayList.

```
((DelegateForest)forest).removeVertex(vertexCentralities.first().getKey(), false);
```

This cast is from my algorithm which removes a vertex in the tree, and keeps the subtrees of that vertex. This is why I need the cast to `DelegateForest<V, E>`

1. How can I extract the trees from my forest such that the trees are of type `Forest<V,E>` so that I may case to `DelegateForest<V, E>` later without a problem?
2. Will I have to modify the source code?
3. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a `DelegateTree` to a `DelegateForest` or vice versa, you can however cast both of them to a `Forest`, since they both implement that interface.

Since your algorithm takes a `Forest` I would expect that you could call the following method with `delegateForest.getTrees()`. And as the two-argument `removeVertex(..., ...)` method isn't specified on an interface, the easiest solution is probably to be inspired by the corresponding code on the `DelegateForest` and implement it locally.

```
public void doAlgorithm( Collection<Tree<K,V>> trees )
{
    for ( Tree<K,V> f : tree )
    {
        // algorithm here - tree is a Forest, and likely a DelegateTree
        removeVertex( tree );
    }
}

private removeVertex( Forest forest )
{
     // As per implementation in DelegateForest...
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: OK, so the problem is that the `removeVertex()` method isn't available on the `Forest` or `Tree` interfaces. Luckily, it is specified by yet another interface: `Hypergraph` of which `Forest` and `Tree` are subinterfaces. I have edited my answer - I believe it will work for you.

Comment: Hmmm... Did you notice that the removeVertex() method I am using is overloaded in DelegateForest to accept a boolean which when false will not delete the subtree of the vertex being removed.

Comment: I've had another look and don't see any easy way for you, since the `removeVertex( V , boolean )` isn't specified by an interface and there is no apparent way to make a `DelegateTree` into a `DelegateForest`. If you can control the "tree-factory" the neat way would be to extend the `DelegateTree` and implement the two-argument `removeVertex` method there, but more likely just implement the method next to your algorithm.